# Passing XML data as a string parameter in the request ServiceStack

Tags: xml, exception, post, serialization, servicestack

I’m using ServiceStack and every time I’m trying to pass XML string as a string parameter or  “< “ symbol  for the POST request  I’m getting an exception: SerializationException - Could not deserialize 'application/xml' request.
Here is an example (This request will generate an exception):

```
<UpdateOrderStatusRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Processing.Order">
  <OrderStatusXmlData>
      <test>something</test>
</OrderStatusXmlData>
</UpdateOrderStatusRequest>
```

However if I’ll pass regular string data, everything works fine:

```
<UpdateOrderStatusRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Processing.Order">
  <OrderStatusXmlData>
      Test string
</OrderStatusXmlData>
</UpdateOrderStatusRequest>
```

Is there any way to use xml or html string inside the xml POST request?

Comment: Did you try using cdata?